# Comprobar campo de entrada numérico en Xamarin

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Tengo método que lo que hace es controlar ciertos campos vacíos. Si están vacios salta el popup, si no se almacenan.

Pero mi duda es la siguiente: ¿Cómo puedo comprobar que estoy metiendo números y no un string por el field de entrada (`txtTelefono.text`) ?

Porque si introduzco una cadena, al estar internamente como entero, me salta el error del IDE y se cierra la aplicación.

Me gustaria meterlo en la misma condición que comprueba los campos vacios a ser posible.

A continuación expongo el código. Gracias de antemano.

```
void evento(object sender, EventArgs a){
    string identificador = txtNif.Text;
    //int telefono = int.Parse(txtTlf.Text);    

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(identificador) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtTlf.Text)) //Compruebo campos
    {
        DisplayAlert("Error", "Mensaje de error", "Back");
    }

    else
    {
        //Casteo el entero
        int telefono = int.Parse(txtTlf.Text);

        if (ID == String.Empty ) //Si el ID autogenerable en la BD está vacio...se almacena.
        { 
            App.AzureService.agregausuario(nif, telefono);
            DisplayAlert("Alerta", "Mensaje satisfactorio", "Back");
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacer esto de varias formas,

### 1. Verificar que todos los caracteres sean dígitos

```
    void evento(object sender, EventArgs a)
    {
        string identificador = txtNif.Text;
        string telefonoText= txtTlf.Text;    

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(identificador) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtTlf.Text)) //Compruebo campos
        {
            DisplayAlert("Error", "Mensaje de error", "Back");
            return;
        }

        if (!telefonoText.ToCharArray().All(Char.IsDigit))
        {
            DisplayAlert("Error", "El telefono debe ser numerico", "Back");
            return;
        }


        //Casteo el entero
        int telefono = int.Parse(txtTlf.Text);

            if (ID == String.Empty) //Si el ID autogenerable en la BD está vacio...se almacena.
            {
                App.AzureService.agregausuario(nif, telefono);
                DisplayAlert("Alerta", "Mensaje satisfactorio", "Back");
            }

    }
```

### 2. Usar una expresion regular

Una expresion regular me permite comprobar que una cadena o parte de ella cumple con un patron. En este caso la expresion regular que puedo usar es:

[image: Regex]

```
    void evento(object sender, EventArgs a)
    {
        var identificador = txtNif.Text;
        string telefonoText = txtTlf.Text;    

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(identificador) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtTlf.Text)) //Compruebo campos
        {
            DisplayAlert("Error", "Mensaje de error", "Back");
            return;
        }
        var regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"^\d{8}$");

        if (!regex.IsMatch(telefonoText))
        {
            DisplayAlert("Error", "El telefono debe ser numerico", "Back");
            return;
        }


        //Casteo el entero
        int telefono = int.Parse(telefonoText);

            if (ID == String.Empty) //Si el ID autogenerable en la BD está vacio...se almacena.
            {
                App.AzureService.agregausuario(nif, telefono);
                DisplayAlert("Alerta", "Mensaje satisfactorio", "Back");
            }

    }
```

> Personalmente te recomendaria guardar el telefono como una cadena por si luego necesitas incluir codigo de pais(+51) o separadores de digitos.

#### Update: Adicionalmente

puedes facilitarle la vida al usuario usando un teclado en particular para ese **Entry**.

```
<Entry Keyboard="Telephone" />
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Reference:** https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/controls/choose-keyboard-for-entry/Images/telephone-winphone.png

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha sido súper util, funciona bien. Un saludo! :D

Comment: Te recomiendo usar el teclado Telephone :)

Comment: Ya lo utilizo Jesús, pero como la aplicación que se está desarrollando 
 es de tipo "Cross Platform" osea, para varias plataformas, en windows por ejemplo no aparece ningún teclado numérico y puedes introducir caracteres sin que lo impida, de ahí la validación.  Gracias de nuevo y un saludo